# file.exists() returns false for existing file in android

Tags: android, image, file, bitmap, decode

In my app user can select image from sdcard and set as profile picture. Everything is working fine but when user selects image from whatsapp folder from sdcard image can not decoded.

I am using following code to decode file and display in ImageView.

```
if (imgFile.exists()) {                                 

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile  
        .getAbsolutePath());                        

imgProfilePic.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);             
myBitmap = null;                                    
System.gc();                                        
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();                          

}
```

I am getting selected image path `/storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20130804-WA0000.jpg` and it exists in sdcard but `file.exists` always returns false. 
It works fine if user selects image from other folders rather than whatsapp.

**Update**

I am following steps like

```
1. click on profilepic(imageview).
2. select options(from camera,galerry,or edit)
3. open selected or captured image in CropImage Activity.
4. display cropped image.
```

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated..Thanks.

Comment: look after the path /storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp...

Comment: it might be the issue of sdcard0...

Comment: Is there any alternative to get image from whatsapp folder ?

Comment: first try to check on toast or by System.out.print that which path exactly u r getting???

Comment: I am getting `/storage/sdcard0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20130804-WA0000.jpg` in log.

Comment: It happens sometimes while selecting the images from another application's folder the images are exists but it always returns the file not found. I have faced this issue, its problem of gallery it sometimes does not get the images from another application folders though the images are actually there.

Comment: @GrIsHu is there any solution ?

Comment: Need to find out a way if exists.

Comment: @GrIsHu solved..posted ans below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was modifying image of other apps. I think this might be the problem. So what I did ?

1. select image and get path in `onActivityResult()`
2. copy image from this path in temp file using below code
3. use temp file for cropping and other processing

```
private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }

}
```

Hope this may help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ImageFile.exists()` method is giving `false` in android, but it exists in memory, then you definitely have not given `Write-external-storage` Permission in the `Manifest` file of Your Project. Add this Permission in the Manifest of Your Project:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: I have all the required permissions in manifest file. However `imgFile.exists()` doesn't require Write-external-storage Permission.