# Google+ 4.3 and above cannot access `/storage/emulated/legacy/` to crop image from it

Tags: java, android, image, storage, google-plus

In my android app i'm asking "google+ photos app" to crop an image under the path

`file:///storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImageCapture.tmp``

then I ask it to save cropped image to `/storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImage.tmp`
I'm using Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2

Here is my code

```
  // Crop and resize the image for profile
  private void cropImage(Uri imageCaptureUri) {
    // Use existing crop activity.
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(imageCaptureUri, AccountSignInDetails.IMAGE_UNSPECIFIED);

    // Specify the output path
    File imageFile =
        new File(ResManager.mAppDir, AccountSignInDetails.PROFILE_IMAGE_FILE);
    intent.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(imageFile));

    // Specify image size
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 100);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 100);

    // Specify aspect ratio, 1:1
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, ImageTaker.REQUEST_CODE_CROP_PHOTO);
  }
```

where

`imageCaptureUri = file:///storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImageCapture.tmp`

`imageFile = /storage/emulated/0/myApp/ProfileImage.tmp`

Any other cropper can access this path

but "Google plus cropper" shows other image (my guess is that it's the last image it could access)

It happens only on Google+ 4.3 and above

returned to 4.2 and the cropper managed to access the photo.

No indicative logcat errors.

how can I fix this?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/20559197/1608643

Comment: look at my update: it happens only on Google+ 4.3 and above